# Huh? Why doesn't playEarcon() produce onUtteranceCompleted()?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

An Android book I have states that using `TextToSpeech.playEarcon()` is preferable to playing audio files (using MediaPlayer) because:

> Instead of having to determine the opportune moment to play an audible
>   cue and relying on callbacks to get the timing right, we can instead
>   queue up our earcons among the text we send to the TTS engine. We then
>   know that our earcons will be played at the appropriate time, and we
>   can use the same pathway to get our sounds to the user, including the
>   **onUtteranceCompleted()** callbacks to let us know where we are.

But my short and simple experiment with this shows this **isn't** the case:

```
String utteranceId = String.valueOf(utteranceNum++);
params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, utteranceId);
params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
tts.speak("FIRST part of sentence", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);

utteranceId = String.valueOf(utteranceNum++);
params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, utteranceId);
params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
tts.playEarcon("[fancyring]", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);

utteranceId = String.valueOf(utteranceNum++);
params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, utteranceId);
params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
tts.speak("SECOND part of sentence", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);
```

When I examine the logs from [onUtteranceCompleted()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html) I only see the utteranceIds of the ones played by `tts.speak()`, not the one played by `tts.playEarcon()`.

Why is this discrepancy? Is there a workaround for this?

**P.S.** At the risk of stating the obvious: All three utterances are played out fine and at the right order. It is only the [onUtteranceCompleted()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html) that isn't called for some reason for the `tts.playEarcon()`.

Comment: The documentation of `playEarcon(...)` says: "*Plays the earcon using the specified queueing mode and parameters. The earcon must already have been added with `addEarcon(String, String)` or `addEarcon(String, String, int)`.*" Not sure why it plays at all, considering above documentation, but might be worth a try?

Comment: @MH I only included the relevant code, to avoid distraction from the main issue. I of course do all the proper initialization, including `addEarcon()` (otherwise it wouldn't have been played, as you correctly noted). Still looking for a solution to this mystery...

Comment: What platform version are you testing your code on? Starting API level 15 `TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener` is deprecated and replaced by `UtteranceProgressListener`. Furthermore, you might want to check the return values for `addEarcon(...)` and `playEarcon(...)`, even though the text gets spoken. Finally, you could try a couple of different TTS engines to see if the behaviour is consistent.

Comment: @MH I am using API 8. I can't use API 15 because my app must be able to run on older Android 2.2 phones... I did try with different TTS engines: They all exhibit the same exact behavior. Looks like this "bug" is by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering myself. The incredibly long and very detailed documentation about [TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html) reads (the emphasis is mine):

> Called when an utterance has been **synthesized**.

An earcon is *never* a result of synthesization, so of course [onUtteranceCompleted()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html) will *never* be called for it. This is by design.

Which gets us back to a new question: If there is no advantage to earcons over playing .mp3 files (using MediaPlayer), why use earcons at all?

Comment: Are you sure that's the reason? [This old thread](http://groups.google.com/group/tts-for-android/browse_frm/thread/6d5feb49a599e9f9) states that you have to add a dummy `KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID` parameter to get the darn thing to call your [onUtteranceCompleted](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener.html#onUtteranceCompleted%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @ef2011 Yes, I am sure. I use the KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID for the `playEarcon()` too but that doesn't help. It doesn't produce an onUtteranceCompleted. Period.