# What in TtsService could explain the lack of onUtteranceCompleted() for playEarcon()?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-mediaplayer, onutterancecompleted

A while ago, I discovered that `playEarcon()` [never produces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144969) `onUtteranceCompleted()`.

At the time I just interpreted the documentation that said "Called when an utterance has been **synthesized**" as `onUtteranceCompleted()` being not applicable for earcons because, an earcon isn't really a result of TTS synthesization.

But looking again Android's source code, I simply can't find an explanation that would justify my interpretation.

A few facts about [my test jig](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10134646):

1. `onUtteranceCompleted()` always arrives for utterance ID preceding the earcon. That utterance is an ordinary TTS utterance, not an earcon.
2. The earcon after that **does** play out (i.e. exactly as intended).
3. `onUtteranceCompleted()` for that earcon **never** shows up. This is very consistent and reproducible behavior.

Delving deep into the TtsService source code, there seem to be only 2 methods that could affect the arrival (or absence) of `onUtteranceCompleted()`:

1. [TtsService.processSpeechQueue()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/tts/TtsService.java#TtsService.processSpeechQueue%28%29)
2. [TtsService.onCompletion()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/tts/TtsService.java#708)

If you examine that code, you will see that a 3rd candidate, [TtsService.getSoundResource()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/tts/TtsService.java#975) is ruled out (as being responsible for the lack of onUtteranceComplete for my earcon) because of fact #2 above: The earcon always plays, hence `getSoundResource()` cannot possibly return null.

Using the same logic, the 1st candidate, [TtsService.processSpeechQueue()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/tts/TtsService.java#TtsService.processSpeechQueue%28%29), can also be ruled out, for the same fact #2: The earcon always plays, hence the following 2 critical statements are always executed:

```
1108   mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
...
1111   mPlayer.start();
```

So, we are left with the 2nd candidate only, [TtsService.onCompletion()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/tts/TtsService.java#708), as a possible explanation for why a `playEarcon()` [never produces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10144969) `onUtteranceCompleted()`:

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
  // mCurrentSpeechItem may become null if it is stopped at the same
  // time it completes.
  SpeechItem currentSpeechItemCopy = mCurrentSpeechItem;
  if (currentSpeechItemCopy != null) {
    String callingApp = currentSpeechItemCopy.mCallingApp;
    ArrayList<String> params = currentSpeechItemCopy.mParams;
    String utteranceId = "";
    if (params != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < params.size() - 1; i = i + 2) {
        String param = params.get(i);
        if (param.equals(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID)) {
          utteranceId = params.get(i + 1);
        }
      }
    }
    if (utteranceId.length() > 0) {
      dispatchUtteranceCompletedCallback(utteranceId, callingApp);
    }
  }
  processSpeechQueue();
}
```

In there, there are only 2 conditions that would fail to produce [dispatchUtteranceCompletedCallback()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/tts/TtsService.java#TtsService.dispatchUtteranceCompletedCallback%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29):

1. currentSpeechItemCopy == null
2. utteranceId.length() == 0

But I know for sure that condition #2 can be ruled out because I log all utteranceIds and the earcon's are definitely there.

Also, examining the entire system log:

```
Log.v(SERVICE_TAG, "TTS callback: dispatch started");
```

The missing `onUtteranceCompleted()` could be the result of [dispatchUtteranceCompletedCallback()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/tts/TtsService.java#TtsService.dispatchUtteranceCompletedCallback%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29) not being called, but it could also be the result of `mCallbacksMap.get(packageName)` returning null.

So, we are left again with 2 possibilities, both of which don't make to me much sense:

1. By the time an earcon's [onCompletion()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/tts/TtsService.java#TtsService.onCompletion%28android.media.MediaPlayer%29) is called, earcon's `mCurrentSpeechItem` is null. But **why?**
2. [mCallbacksMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/tts/TtsService.java#1223) is empty. What is it and when does it ever get populated?

Any suggestions or other explanations for solving this mystery?

Comment: We have the same problem, the workaround is to add an empty utterance after the earcon.  It also looks like newer API versions (16) *do* produce the callback for earcons, looking into this.

Comment: There is also a nasty race condition in the `TextToSpeech` contstructor that causes your `onInit` handler to access NULL (about 1% chance) for the TTS engine, since it doesn't come in the callback parameters!  It actually calls your `onInit` before the constructor finishes executing.  This is very serious, because they expect you to do the initialization (`setOnUtteranceComplete`, `addEarcon`) in `onInit`.

Comment: Checked in emulators and `playEarcon` now sends a callback when it is done playing.  This is on API 15 and higher.  You can use the workaround i mentioned in previous comment for lower APIs.

Comment: @escape-llc Thanks++. This is exactly the workaround I've bee using for APIs lower than 15, but the fact that I don't understand why this is happening drives me crazy. Any ideas?

Comment: btw your analysis is good, thanks for taking the time.  but notice that the `Map` that gets passed in the original `TextToSpeech` call is nowhere to be found in that `onCompletion` handler; it is transformed to an `ArrayList` somewhere beforehand, perhaps the defect is in that code?  Perhaps `playEarcon` doesn't propagate that?  Also that service talks to an `Engine` service, so that may also be a place where something doesn't propagate, I have not examined the implementation in any detail.  Look at whatever sets up `mCurrentSpeechItem`.

Answer (score 2):

Check [android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech#playEarcon()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.java?av=h#789) at line [807](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.java?av=h#807). The params argument passed to the text-to-speech service binder is null, which means the service never receives your utterance ID.

```
 public int playEarcon(String earcon, int queueMode,
         HashMap<String,String> params) {
     synchronized (mStartLock) {
         ...
         result = mITts.playEarcon(mPackageName, earcon, queueMode, null);
     }
     ...
 }
```